# Performance Issue with List<byte>

Tags: c#, .net, list, performance, byte

I have a file (~30MB) which I read with File.ReadAllBytes()
This File has a lot of structed data with different length (no terminator in between). So I have to check the length of the first data, cut it out and continue with the next one and so on and on.
Therefore splitting it up in different Tasks is not possible.

Is there any other way to speed this up? (currently taking about 20minutes)

```
    List<Record> Records = new List<Record>  
    internal static void Import(List<byte> filedata)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (filedata.Count > 0)
            {
                Record record = new Record()
                filedata = record.GetData(filedata);
                Records.Add(record)
            }
        });
    }
      
    //inside class "Record"
    internal List<byte> GetData(List<byte> filedata)
    {
        this.length = BitConverter.ToUInt32(new byte[4] { filedata[8], filedata[9], filedata[10], filedata[11] }, 0);
        this.data = new byte[this.length + 1];
        filedata.CopyTo(0, this.data, 0, this.length);
        filedata.RemoveRange(0, 16 + this.length);
        return filedata;
    }
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to be doing? You just keep replacing `this.data` with new arrays. That seems rather pointless.

Comment: What does row mean here? A certain amount of bytes(a fixed block length)? And if you are talking about a file why it  is a List<bytes> and not a stream? Stream seems way more fitting here.

Comment: @Sweeper: sry, i edited the code.. it should make more sense now, what I'm trying to do

Comment: @Ralf i updated the description. The data inside of the file have different length. Is is a list of Bytes, cause I read the File with "File.ReadAllBytes()" and changed it into List<byte>

Comment: Why don't you just use a `Stream` to do this? Then you won't be making a copy of the data every time you read a record!

Comment: Don't read all the data in memory, that's what streaming is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's less about how you can make it better, and more that you couldn't possibly make it worse. There are some serious algorithmic and framework misunderstandings going on here, so much so that I'd recommend re-education for the person that wrote this.

On to specifics:

- don't allocate an array just to extract a number out of your byte buffer, you could just write it out by hand using 4th grade math, or use a built-in function like [MemoryMarshal.Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast?view=net-7.0#system-runtime-interopservices-memorymarshal-cast-2(system-readonlyspan((-0)))) to re-interpret the bytes in place.
- you shouldn't return an array (a list, in fact!!) of data from your main array, you should just extract what you actually need and return that in a `struct`. If you really aren't able to do that for whatever reason, you have spans and `ArraySegment` to avoid allocating a new list and copying data around for no reason.
- `filedata.RemoveRange(0, 16 + this.length);` now the person is just being absolutely lazy. Removing items from the beginning of an array (a list, in fact, again) is a linear operation, just keep an index of the last processed byte and move it forward as you're processing your data.

Comment: And to add to this: I think the entire thing could be done using a `Stream` (perhaps wrapping the stream in a `StreamReader` to make it easier to read `int` etc, if necessary).

Comment: Mhm, I'd have added that as well, but he only mentioned how he got his buffer in a comment after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to read and parse binary data manually is to use a [BinaryReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=net-7.0). This uses an underlying stream to read data directly from a file, or memory, or somewhere else. This helps with performance since it avoids unnecessary copies of data.

Whenever you process binary data you should most likely either use Streams or `Span<byte>`, especially if writing a library or API.

Reading an array of bytes may look something like this:

```
    public byte[] GetByteArrayData(BinaryReader br)
    {
        var length = br.ReadInt32();
        var data = new byte[length];
        var readBytes = br.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        if (length != readBytes)
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException("Stream ended prematurely");
        }
        return data;
    }
```

If you want to read arrays other value types you can allocate your array of your specific type, use [MemoryMarshal.Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast?view=net-7.0#system-runtime-interopservices-memorymarshal-cast-2(system-readonlyspan((-0)))) to cast this array to a `span<byte>`, and use `Read(Span<Byte>)` to fill the array.

Reading a complex object might look something like this:

```
public record Person(string Name, int Age, string FavoriteToy);
public Person Read(Stream stream)
{
    using var br = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.Default, true);
    var version = br.ReadInt32();
    if (version == 1)
    {
        var name = br.ReadString();
        var age = br.ReadInt32();
        return new Person(name, age, "not set");
    }
    else if (version == 2)
    {
        var name = br.ReadString();
        var age = br.ReadInt32();
        var favoriteToy = br.ReadString();
        return new Person(name, age, favoriteToy);
    }
    throw new InvalidDataException($"Unexpected version of Person: {version}");
}
```

However, if you have control over the serialization part I would highly recommend using a (binary) serialization library instead. I have used Protobuf .Net, but there are many others. This will likely be more flexible, reliable, faster, and easier anything you would create yourself.